# What is the typical roundtrip time for a call Cordova webview->native->webview?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, webview

I am evaluating a systemarchitecture where a lot of calls are made between a Cordova webview and the native app. My question is: In what range is the time consumption for the turnaround cordova-native-cordova? Android, IOS, Windows?

Comment: in my apps, its like 0.00000002 s

Comment: oh really? I did a small test and it took 120ms on android Huawei G7...